Error: creating MWAA Environment - ValidationException: All subnets do not belong to the user's account
I am trying to create airflow env accross account; The subnets are in aws account1 and the env is in aws account2 .. (I am sharing the vpc in account2 with account1 using the subnets sharing)
resource "aws_mwaa_environment" "mwaa" {
  count                           = upper(var.env) == "TST" || upper(var.env) == "REC" ? 1 : 0
  name                            = "${module.std_naming_mwaa.name}-mwaa-environnement"
  airflow_version                 = var.airflow_version
  environment_class               = var.environment_class
  min_workers                     = var.min_workers
  max_workers                     = var.max_workers
  dag_s3_path                     = "dags"
  plugins_s3_object_version       = var.plugins_s3_object_version
  plugins_s3_path                 = var.plugins_s3_path
  requirements_s3_path            = "requirements.txt"
  execution_role_arn              = aws_iam_role.mwaa[0].arn
  airflow_configuration_options   = var.airflow_configuration_options
  source_bucket_arn               = module.mwaa_s3[0].arn
  webserver_access_mode           = var.webserver_access_mode
  weekly_maintenance_window_start = var.weekly_maintenance_window_start
  network_configuration {
    security_group_ids = [data.aws_security_group.cnr_mwaa_endpoints_sg[0].id]
    subnet_ids         = data.aws_subnets.subnet_mwaa.ids
  }
  logging_configuration {
    dag_processing_logs {
      enabled   = true
      log_level = "INFO"
    }
    scheduler_logs {
      enabled   = true
      log_level = "INFO"
    }
    task_logs {
      enabled   = true
      log_level = "INFO"
    }
    webserver_logs {
      enabled   = true
      log_level = "INFO"
    }
    worker_logs {
      enabled   = true
      log_level = "INFO"
    }
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      plugins_s3_object_version,
      requirements_s3_object_version,
      startup_script_s3_object_version
    ]
  }
}

I got this error msg:
Error: creating MWAA Environment (cnr-auxo-tst-dom1-mwaa-mwaa-environnement): operation error MWAA: CreateEnvironment, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 500595f9-5590-47df-890d-4ab5285a0eb0, ValidationException: All subnets do not belong to the user's account

Knowing that I managed to create an env airflow accross account via the aws console, does anyone has an explication please or could help with the config, in order to fix this issue .. (I can share more details if needed)
Thank you in advance

I got the same issue as you, use endpoint_management = "CUSTOMER" into your MWAA resource, and it will solve the problem.
This argument is not well explained in the Terraform documentation.

Yes, I confirm .. I resolved this issue by changing the endpoint_management to Customer but forget to mention it here, thank you for your response :) !
